# Will using my phone whilst charging make it charge slower?

Tags: charging

Just the question in the title.  If I have my phone plugged in and charging, will it take any longer to get up to 100% charge if I'm using it or will this make no difference?   (I'm using a galaxy nexus)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  The Galaxy Nexus will accept no more than 4.5W of power (0.9A @ 5V) from a charger, regardless of what the charger is capable of supplying.

This isn't a whole lot, so doing stuff will cut down on the amount of power available to charge the battery and it's actually possible to run down the battery while you're plugged in.  Testing by a [guy on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/nystt/galaxy_nexus_power_analysis_why_chargers_cant/) showed peak power draws from the battery of over 5W when using google maps, so you'd end up using the entire charger supply to power the hardware, and another 0.5W drawn from the battery.

Comment: I can verify being able to use more power than I'm able to draw. While out driving around playing Ingress, even with the phone plugged into my car charger, between the app, GPS, mobile data, and the screen, my battery charge level still went down. (And it got damn hot, too.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will take longer to charge if you're using it. The same as when you're using a laptop while it's charging.